# set mobx store in const value in react native

Tags: react-native, api, axios, mobx, asyncstorage

how can i set const value using mobx obeserve data? as i don't know how can i define props here.

```
export const BASE_URL = base_url_from_mobx
```

i have some data in this function. From there i will have some confidential data and a base url. This ApiKeys is a native module

```
ApiKeys.getApiKeys((data)=>{
    let secureData = JSON.parse(data)
}
```

i have an api.js file where i set the interceptor and set the base url like below

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    timeout: 10 * 1000,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    }
});
```

here **BASE_URL** is defined and export as const in **constants.js** file but now i want to set it from the value i have got from the function.
This can be done if i can do like below

```
const api = axios.create({
    // baseURL: BASE_URL,
    baseURL: (JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem(SECURE_KEY))).SOHOJ_APP_API_BASE_URL_DEVELOPMENT,
    timeout: 10 * 1000,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    }
});
```

but it is giving me issue like

[image]

how can i do that. my i use to make a request like below using **api.js**

```
api
    .post('api_end_point',parameters,headers)
    .then(response=>{

    })
    .catch(error =>{

    })
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is some issue with your `AsyncStorage.getItem(SECURE_KEY)` ,probably it's not a proper json object.do a console.log of `AsyncStorage.getItem(SECURE_KEY)` and see what value you get.

Comment: paste here the output of the console.log of AsyncStorage.getItem(SECURE_KEY)

Comment: when i do this.. 

AsyncStorage.getItem(SECURE_KEY).then(value =>{
    console.log('SECURE_KEY: ',value)
})

i get the data but i cannot do that inside there... please see my const api

Comment: i did not get you ? i am just asking that what output you are getting from AsyncStorage.getItem(SECURE_KEY) ?

Comment: i am getting a json string as a output.. and then i turn it into a json object... but the problem is with promise

Comment: yea so i am saying that to paste the json string output.because error is while parsing that json string.